How to edit text of new user email?
On my WordPress website (6.6.2), I would like to edit the current automatic new user email template.
Actually I don't want to delete the current content, but I just want to add some text.
Thanks for any help.

look at this filter https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/new_user_email_content/. if you need more help, edit your question to show us the code you tried.

If you accept a plugin too, Better Notifications for WP allows you to edit that email: https://wordpress.org/plugins/bnfw/
